# JQuery Dialog with content that depends on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I'm the midst of creating a form inside a dialog window with jQuery.

I'm currently loading a partial view with the jQuery load() function, and then adding the view into a jQuery UI dialog box. The partial view contains an html form which also contains a validation script in the markup.

This is how I load the view and instantiate the dialog window:

```
$('<div/>').load('/controller/view #targetDiv').dialog();
```

Unfortunately the load() function discards the script inside the partial view. :(

The validation script is important since it makes ajax calls to the form controller on an 'input blur' event, and returns the server side form-validation response. This means that the validation script must run continuously on the form inside the dialog.

The problem is that I load the view but there is no javascript.

Are there any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save the javascript codes in a separate `.js` file and use [`getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method.

> Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.